# Работа с LongPoll VK C#

Tags: c#, вконтакте

Объясните на коде, как подключаться к LongPoll серверу, как получать ответ и т.д.
Буду очень благодарен

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll, смотрели?

Comment: Да, там PHP, а мне нужен C#. Мне нужен пример кода)

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1588580.html#post8376511

Comment: @NMD не подходит вами предложенная тема. Мне нужна работа с Messages.LongPollHistory)